# Why do people prefer to use List Item Collection Enumeratror over the get_data method?

Tags: javascript, jsom, best-practices, api

I wonder if anyone compared the two methods of handling `ListItemCollection` data in javascript:

```
var enumerator = collection.getEnumerator();
while(enumerator.moveNext()) {var current = enumerator.get_current(); /*...*/}
// vs.
var data = collection.get_data(), count = collection.get_count();
var index = 0, item = count > 0 ? data[index] : null, fieldValues = item ? item.get_fieldValues() : null;
```

Are there any drawbacks to the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are parts of the code from sp.runtime.js:

```
SP.ClientObjectCollection = function SP_ClientObjectCollection(context, objectPath) {
    this.getEnumerator = this.$3M_1;
    SP.ClientObjectCollection.initializeBase(this, [context, objectPath]);
};
SP.ClientObjectCollection.prototype = {
//...
    $3M_1: function SP_ClientObjectCollection$$3M_1() {
        this.$2n_1(); /* checks that this.$2_1 is not null, otherwise throws CollectionNotInitialized exception */
        return new SP.ArrayListEnumerator(this.get_data());
    },
    get_count: function SP_ClientObjectCollection$get_count() {
        this.$2n_1();
        return (this.get_data()).length;
    },
    $2_1: null,
    get_data: function SP_ClientObjectCollection$get_data() {
        if (!this.$2_1) {
            this.$2_1 = [];
        }
        return this.$2_1;
    },
    fromJson: /* parses json response from executeQueryAsync and initializes this.$2_1 as an array of SP_ListItem objects */
//...
};
```

Take a look at $3M_1 function which is an alias for getEnumerator.
It just wraps array in a new object (ArrayListEnumerator):

```
SP.ArrayListEnumerator = function SP_ArrayListEnumerator($p0) {
    this.$2_0 = $p0;
    this.$M_0 = -1;
    this.$2K_0 = $p0.length;
    this.current = null;
};
SP.ArrayListEnumerator.prototype = {
    $2_0: null,
    $M_0: 0,
    $2K_0: 0,
    get_current: function SP_ArrayListEnumerator$get_current() {
        return this.$2_0[this.$M_0];
    },
    moveNext: function SP_ArrayListEnumerator$moveNext() {
        if (this.$2K_0 !== this.$2_0.length) {
            throw Error.invalidOperation(SP.ResResources.getString('CollectionModified'));
        }
        this.$M_0++;
        this.current = this.$2_0[this.$M_0];
        return this.$M_0 < this.$2_0.length;
    },
    reset: function SP_ArrayListEnumerator$reset() {
        this.$M_0 = -1;
        this.current = null;
    }
};
```

**tl;dr:**
I don't think there's any drawback to the latter.
On the contrary, it's faster and, imho, in most cases cleaner.

> [p.s.] get_count can throw CollectionNotInitialized exception while get_data always returns you an array. Below is slightly faster and probably (arguably) safer:

```
var data = collection.get_data(), count = data.length;
```

Comment: Why am I not surprised to see a great answer from you Alex?  :)